# How can I sort an object by two unique fields in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I need to sort an array of objects by the two fields. I need it to be as least computationally heavy as possible.

This is how the array of objects looks

```
let arr = [
    {
        name: 'Liate',
        surname: 'Tsek'
    },
    ...
]
```

This is how I am doing it

```
let unique = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.name))]
```

This only works for the 1st field, how can I get it to work with both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let seen = new Set()
let uniArr = arr.filter(entry => {
    /*
    ** Create unique key of code and segment
    */
    const key = entry.name+ "-" + entry.surname
    /*
    **  Check if the key does not exist in the SET
    */
    const keep = !seen.has(key)
    /*
    ** If keep doesn't exist, add it to the set
    */
    if (keep)
        seen.add(key)
    /*
    ** Return
    */
    return keep
})
```

This works given that the delimiter you use to join the fields will never appear in either fields. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Thank you, this worked for me. I am keen to know what the `Set` is? I am new to NodeJS apologies.

Comment: I filter with ES6 Set, I recommend learning more about it before continuing